# How to Make Page close popup Box when click on page parts other then the popup box and its inner content using Javascript DOM Targeting Childnode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, target

I am trying to make a function using javascript. The function: when I click on different pictures and it shows a different popout display and when i click on the page besides the pop-out desplay, the display close (similar to Facebook function when user click on the "message picture, and Notification picture).  My code is below. Every time I try to click on the picture it Open and close the box imediately.  When I click the node within the box. I also close.  These should not be happening.  Can you guys tell me what is wrong with my code.  Thank a lot

**HTML:**

```
<!--Image-->
<a href="#"  onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggle(\'toggle\')>
    <img id="no" type="image" src="/img/con.png"  width="20" height="20" alt="Notes">
</a>

<!--Panel-->
<div id="panelA">
    <div id="innerPanel">
        <div id="inn">Order Notification</div>
        <div id="content_wrap">
            <div id="content">
                Bla BLa BLa bla bla
            </div>
            <div id="content2">
                Hay Hay hay
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggle(x){
    var pa = document.getElementById(x);
    if(pa.style.display == "block"){
       pa.style.display = "none";
    } else {
       pa.style.display = "block";
    }
}

var boxArray = ['a','b'];
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    var picId= _("pictureId");
    for(var i=0; i < boxArray.length; i++){
        var box = _(boxArray[i]);
        if(event.target != xom && event.target.parentNode != xom){
             box.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you heard of bootstrap modal??

Comment: Thank James.  It is "var box" above.

Comment: Thanks James,  It is "var box" above